# Writing printf from C program to single line of console from shell script

Tags: c, linux, sh

I have a shell script that has a function that displays a status, something along the lines of:

```
display() {
  clear
  echo -e "      Download In Progress\n"
  echo -e "          Please Wait \n"
  echo -e "   Step: $*"
}
```

The shell script then does its main work

```
display " 1 starting"
does some work
display " 2 complete"
display " 2 starting" 
does some work
display " 2 complete"
```

My problem is that one of my "does some work" is a C program with several printf statements in them.  Currently I've got the stdout redirected to a log file so that I can see them somewhere:

```
display " 1 starting"
/usr/bin/mycprogram >> /tmp/mylogfile.lg
display " 2 complete"
```

But what I really want is to have the stdout written to the "Step: " line.  I can simply take the redirect off and the output is displayed to the screen, but it goes line by line and pushing the neat "Download in Progress" off the screen and leaves an ugly trail of messages.

How would I accomplish putting the individual printf messages all to the same line and keep my header?

Answer (score 1):

```
/usr/bin/mycprogram |  awk '{printf("%s, ",$0)}'
```

for example is one way to make it into a single line
If you want a way of disabling line wrappling you can try

```
echo -ne "\x1b[?7l"
```

but in might not work on all the terminals. Disabling line wrapping will surely stop vertical scrolling but might make a mess of other output you would like to wrap. When you want linewrap back

```
echo -ne "\x1b[?7h"
```

If you don't want echo to automatically put a newline at the end of the string echoed (so that then the executable output goes on the same line:

```
echo -n "this will not put a newline at the end"
```

Supposing you want it all including the linewrap thing:

```
echo -ne "Starting Step: $* \x1b[?7l"
/usr/bin/mycprogram |  awk '{printf("%s, ",$0)}'
echo -ne "\x1b[?7h"
```

Comment: That's ALMOST what I think the OP wants. For with GNU awak you can have every line from the program *overwrite the same* line `awk '{printf("\r%*s\r%s",length($0), " ", $0)}'`

Comment: if the line gets too long it will still push stuff off the screen anyway. I'm not entirely sure on what the OP exactly wants. Maybe I should have asked first.

Comment: I think the OP just wants to prevent vertical scrolling, while still outputting every line of input (possibly to the same line)

Comment: you can keep on suppressing "\n" but if there is some other output at some point linewrap will vertical scroll ... well unless you disable linewrapping.

Comment: If you happen to think my answer is any good please help my reputation and mark my answer as usefull.

Comment: Last edit shows a way that will not do vertical scrolling even for very many lines of output from program. Hope that's enough to be accepted as the good answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say without seeing you're c code, but I would guess that you are specifying newlines:

```
printf("%s\n", s);
```

If you remove the newlines from the c file printf's then they will appear on the same line (you might want to include some other separator like "\t"):

```
printf("%s\t", s);
```

You also don't want a new line to be given by the console output, `echo` does this by default, but if you specify `-n` it will not:

```
echo -n "Step:"; ./c_program;
```